# 2-norm and infinty norm of a system in controls

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimal-control, l2-norm

How to compute 2-norm or infinity norm of following system?

[image: figure]

i am confused whether to calculate using simple matrix theory "where it don't regard for s domain" or H2 and H-infinty norm. Thanks in advance.
The problem is 4.4 from book Essentials of Robust Control

Answer (score 2):

You probably know that matrix norms can be defined by the vector norms in the following way:
\begin{equation}
||A||:= \max_{x\neq 0} \frac{||Ax||}{||x||}
\end{equation}
for a matrix $A$. So you just look up the definition for the infinity or 2-norm and plug it into the expression above.
When doing this you will further realize that the following equalities hold:
\begin{equation}
||A||_\infty = \max\limits_i \sum\limits_{j}|a_{ij}|\\
||A||_2= \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^HA)}
\end{equation}
So for the infinity norm you sum up the absolute values in each row and take the the row with the largest sum. For the 2-norm you need to find the eigenvalue with the largest absolute value for the matrix $A^HA$. Note when you have the variable $s$ in your matrix the norms might also be functions of $s$.

Comment: I am afraid that this answer is missing some important context. In control theory there is a standard definition of norms for control systems that does not coincide with the definition of matrix norms; see e.g. Section 2.2 in http://users.abo.fi/htoivone/courses/robust/rob2.pdf . Clearly OP is confused about those.

Comment: Yes you are right, I wasn't aware of that since I don't work in control theory. But your link should provide the definitions needed.

Comment: thanks .....
i read the link provided by Federico Poloni, the above question would be solved using H2 and H-infinite norm definitions.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I'm not sure if you got my note, hoping you would find time to write an Answer based on your upvoted Comment above.

Comment: @hardmath I can see your answer if I go to my account page and click on "helpful flags", but it is without signature (I don't know who wrote it), and I didn't get any notifications about it.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni:  Good to know -- I'm new at this!